# Hornet Dashboard not working: the client is not using the websocket protocol

Tags: hornet, hornet-dashboard

Just recently installed a hornet node. The api works when I use the `pyota` libaray. But the hornet dashboard is not working.

When I load the page is says "not synced" even though through the api I can see that it is indeed synced.

Through the hornet logs I see the waning:

```
WARN        Dashboard        websockethub/hub.go:204        upgrade websocket error: websocket: the client is not using the websocket protocol: 'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header
```

What does this mean and why do you think the hornet desktop is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using nginx to connect to the hornet dashboard. When using nginx to connect you must set the `Upgrade` and `Connection` header properly ([src](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-configure-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-websocket)):

```
location / {
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
}
```

Along with any other proxy header information. In full this is my nginx entry:

```
location / {                                                                                                                                                                       
  proxy_set_header        Host $host;                                                                                                                                               
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                                                                                                                                   
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                                                                               
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;                                                                                                                                
  proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;                                                                                                                                    
  proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";                                                                                                                                     
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;                                                                                                                                                 
 }
```